# Modify a specific object member of an array of objects through passing

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, member

I want to modify a specific object member of an array of objects. So I intend to pass the object member to a method that would iterate through the array and modify the specified member for each object:

```
Object *objs[10];
if (condition)
   modify_all(objs, Object.x, set_value);
```

But I can't pass Object.x like that. Is there a better way of doing this?
I need something like this, since modfiy_all doesn't know which member to modify.

EDIT: I'm just trying to refactor repetitive iterations of the array.

Comment: you might be able to use templates to do this, see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/672843/33499)

Comment: That sounds a bit complicated but I'm going to give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: yes, it is complicated, but what you are trying to do is a bit strange. It is probably easier not to use a function at all and just juse a for loop. If you use c++11, you can use a callback with lambda function as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a char or an int instead of the object member, and that string or int will specify which member should be modified. For example:

```
Object *objs[10];
if (condition)
   modify_all(objs, "x", set_value);
```

or

```
Object *objs[10];
if (condition)
   modify_all(objs, 0, set_value);
```

Inside modify_all you can use a switch statement based on this parameter sent.

Comment: Yes, I thought of doing that. However I have about 12 object members and it gets confusing matching them up with integers or chars.

Comment: You can use an ENUM to better identify them and not get confused

Comment: You need to provide mapping between member variables and the parameter values.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do. But I couldn't find anywhere where they mapped anything to member variables!