# typedef declaration syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, boost, typedef

Some days ago I looked at boost sources and found interesting **typedef**.

There is a code from "boost\detail\none_t.hpp":

```
namespace boost {

namespace detail {

struct none_helper{};

typedef int none_helper::*none_t ;

} // namespace detail

} // namespace boost
```

I didn't see syntax like that earlier and can't explain the sense of that.

This **typedef** introduces name "none_t" as pointer to int in boost::detail namespace.

What the syntax is?

And what difference between "**typedef int none_helper::*none_t**" and for example "**typedef int *none_t**" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is for a pointer to member - here it typedefs `none_t` as a pointer to an `int` data member of `none_helper`.

The syntax can be used e.g. this way:

```
 struct X { int i; };

 typedef int X::*PI;
 PI pi = &X::i;
 X* x = foo();
 x->*pi = 42;
```

InformIT has an [article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=142) on member pointers, containing more details.

Answer (score 1):

- `typedef int* none_t;` introduces type alias for pointer to integer.
- `typedef int non_helper::*none_t;` introduces type alias for pointer to integer member of `non_helper` class.

Answer (score 1):

`none_t` is a pointer to member variable with type `int` of `none_helper`.

```
struct none_helper
{
  int x1;
  int x2;
};

int none_helper::* ptm = &none_helper::x1;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     none_t
```