# If I can take a normal pointer to a variable within a class, what's the point of class member pointers?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, member

Take this code:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int var;

    mystruct() : var(0) {}
};

int main()
{
    mystruct ins;

    int* p = &ins.var;

    *p = 1;
}
```

So what are some concrete really good examples of uses for the class member pointer?

```
int    X::*p = &X::data; /* p contains offset */
X      object;
X      *objptr = new X;

int    i = object.*p;
int    j = objptr->*p;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: Pointer to class data member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the your question is about pointers of pointer-to-*data*-member type. In C++ there are also pointers of pointer-to-member-*function* type. The two have something in common at some abstract level, but otherwise they are different.

Pointer of pointer-to-data-member type is applicable to *any* instance of the class. An ordinary pointer always points to a member of a *specific* instance of the class. Pointer of pointer-to-data-member type is a higher level implementation of the idea of "run-time offset" from the beginning of a class object. It is a *relative* pointer. In that way it is completely different thing from ordinary pointers, which are *absolute* pointers.

To illustrate that with an example, let's say you have an array of classes with three members of the same type `x`, `y` and `z`

```
struct Point { int x, y, z; };

Point point_array[N];
```

and you need to set all members with the same name to `0` in the entire array, without changing any other members. Here's how you can do it using a pointer of pointer-to-data-member type

```
void zero_members(Point points[], int n, int Point::*m) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    points[i].*m = 0;
}
```

Now, by using this function you can do

```
zero_members(point_array, N, &Point::x);
```

to set all `x`s to zero. Or you can do

```
zero_members(point_array, N, &Point::y);
```

to set all `y`s to zero. You do can all this with a *single* function, and what's also important, the member selection is performed by a *run-time* parameter (as opposed to a *compile-time* one).

You cannot do something like this with ordinary pointers. In fact, you can't do it in any other way.

Answer (score 3):

So that you can access the member on multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, this is akin to asking for good examples of using `goto`... ;-) Okay, it's there, and sometimes it can be handy, but any example of "good" use of `goto` is likely to be disputed. And so also for member pointers, they're pretty low-level.

For member function pointers one common usage is in event-driven systems. Package a member function pointer together with a pointer to an object of the relevant class, and you have something very much like a C# delegate. You can then pass this little functor package around, and someone else's code, e.g. a GUI framework, can call back on your object without even knowing about it.

The Boost library provides some support for that, e.g. `boost::function` and `boost::bind`, and so does TR1 and the upcoming C++0x standard library (essentially a subset of the Boost functionality).

I can't offhand think of any common usage of data member pointers, though.

Regarding "low level", member pointers follow special rules which let you inadvertently bypass a `protected` access restriction.

Cheers & hth.,

– Alf

Comment: They are higher-level than regular pointers, or the closest alternative `offsetof`. (For evidence, note that pointer-to-member types are larger than actual pointers.) Bypassing access restrictions with a PTM is no different from exposing a pointer to a private instance member. There are no special rules, and I can't imagine doing that accidentally.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Hi. The particular special rule I referred to is C++98 §4.11/2. Searching for a discussion of this the first concrete example I found was [http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_frm/thread/100c8b0851250de/04fb4a8884b2d6b9], by me. The first hit Google served up, however, was [http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_frm/thread/113d27ced1bdcaa7/6e569f4e17eb63da]. ;-) Regarding abstraction levels, I don't find it meaningful to compare higher/lower level between regular pointers and member pointers.