# What are the requirements on type for this template function

Tags: c++, generics, function

I am looking at C++ code that looks like this :

```
template<class A>
bool foo(int A::*)
{ /*blah*/ }
```

What is the `int A::*` construct? What requirement does it impose on the type `A`?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Here is a nice long SO thread on this exact topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int A::*` is a pointer to an `int` data member of type `A`. E.g., given the types:

```
struct Foo { int i; };
struct Bar { double d; };
```

- `int Foo::*` is a pointer to an `int` data member of type `Foo`, whose only valid values are null and the address of `Foo::i`
- `int Bar::*` is a pointer to an `int` data member of type `Bar`, whose only valid value is null, as `Bar` contains no `int` data members

The only requirement imposed on type `A` is that it is not a primitive type, as primitive types obviously cannot have data members.