# Using template instead of switch

Tags: c++, templates

I want to perform a set of tests in my code that are similar but change only depending on a parameter.

I could write this using a switch statement:

```
bool doTest(EnumSensorFamily family, const StructSensorProposal& proposed)
{
  switch (family)
  {
  case FAM1:
    return (ExpectedFam1 == proposed.Fam1SensorId);
    break;
  case FAM2:
    return (ExpectedFam2 == proposed.Fam2SensorId);
    break;
  case FAM3:
    return (ExpectedFam3 == proposed.Fam3SensorId);
    break;
  default:
    ERROR ("Unexpected family");
    return false;
  }
}
```

I was thinking of doing this with template specialisations

```
template <EnumSensorFamily family>
bool doTest(const StructSensorProposal& proposed);

template<>
bool doTest<FAM1> (const StructSensorProposal& proposed)
{
  return (ExpectedFam1 == proposed.Fam1SensorId);
}

template<>
bool doTest<FAM2> (const StructSensorProposal& proposed)
{
  return (ExpectedFam2 == proposed.Fam2SensorId);
}

template<>
bool doTest<FAM3> (const StructSensorProposal& proposed)
{
  return (ExpectedFam3 == proposed.Fam3SensorId);
}
```

Is there any benefit of doing this apart from avoiding a switch statement containing near identical cases?

Ideally I would like to be able to write single method to reduce the maintenance overhead.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building off Andrew's answer...

Note that the `EnumSensorFamily family` must be known at compile time.  If it is not known until run time, then you'll have to write a `switch` to choose the template, putting you back where you started.

Another way to do this is with the Traits pattern:

```
template <EnumSensorFamily family>
struct SensorTraits;

template <>
struct SensorTraits<FAM1>
{
    const EnumSensorFamily kFamilyID = ExpectedFam1;
};

template <>
struct SensorTraits<FAM2>
{
    const EnumSensorFamily kFamilyID = ExpectedFam2;
};

template <>
struct SensorTraits<FAM3>
{
    const EnumSensorFamily kFamilyID = ExpectedFam3;
};

template <EnumSensorFamily family>
bool doTest(const StructSensorProposal& proposed)
{
  return (SensorTraits<family>::kFamilyID == proposed.Fam1SensorId);
}
```

If you try to use `doTest` with a sensor family that lacks a traits specialization, you get a compile error. Also note that you never instantiate a traits object, you just use its definitions.

This lets you reuse constants, typedefs, whatever in several functions. Additionally, adding a new family does not involve combing through all the code looking for every `switch` statement that cares. All you have to do is create a new `SensorTraits` specialization.

**EDIT:** You can make the field dependent on the sensor family with a [pointer to member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member):

```
template <>
struct SensorTraits<FAM1>
{
    const EnumSensorFamily kFamilyID = ExpectedFam1;
    int StructSensorProposal::*proposalField = &StructSensorProposal::fam1field;
};

// ...

template <EnumSensorFamily family>
int getProposedField(const StructSensorProposal& proposed)
{
    return proposed.*SensorTraits<family>::proposalField;
}
```

You can also put in, say, a `typedef` for the sensor's data type:

```
template <>
struct SensorTraits<FAM1>
{
    const EnumSensorFamily kFamilyID = ExpectedFam1;
    typedef uint16_t data_type;
    data_type StructSensorProposal::*proposalField = &StructSensorProposal::fam1field;
};

// ...

template <EnumSensorFamily family>
SensorTraits<family>::data_type getProposedField(const StructSensorProposal& proposed)
{
    return proposed.*SensorTraits<family>::proposalField;
}
```

I haven't tested these; you might need a `const` or `static` in there.

Comment: Can I use a similar mechanism to select the filed in the proposed structure? Each sensor family has a separate field in the proposal.

Comment: I put a static method inside traits to return the corrected prosed sensor depending on the family.

Comment: I had a method inside the traits implementation: `template <> struct SensorTraits<FAM1> { static EnumSensorId getProposed(const StructSensorProposal& proposed) {return proposed.Fam1SensorId;} };` It certainly seemed to work. Is there any disadvantage to this?

Comment: That's a perfectly workable alternative. It can be a little less clear to someone else (a getter function could have side effects, while a member dereference is pretty explicit), but the reverse could be true if the reader doesn't understand member pointers.

Answer (score 6):

The benefit is a very small potential performance improvement if the compiler fails to optimize the `switch` properly (i.e. if it doesn't generate the same code as for the template solution, which is doable for a modern, inlining compiler). **Of course only if `family` is a compile-time constant** - otherwise templates are not applicable and the best optimization that the compiler could find for the `switch` would be a computed jump or a jump table.

If your code always looks like `return (ExpectedFamN == proposed.FamNSensorId);`, I'd rather use arrays for the expected values and the sensor IDs and index those based on the `family`.

Comment: I used the suggestion to set up an array of expected values, but followed up Mike's suggestion to determine the sensor field. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well in a way... you are moving processing away from run time to compile time. The compiler will create the functions and use them accordingly instead of at run time having to go through the switch statement.

Also, it will result in cleaner code.

Comment: Cleaner code is definitely a subjective matter. I personally would find the `switch` much cleaner since i don't create and read templated source all the time. (Not counting STL usage.)

Comment: @RedX: On the flipside, as I pointed out, adding a sensor family means finding every `switch` and adding the needed `case`.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to use templates in the following case:

```
const  EnumSensorFamily familyCompileTime = FAM3; // Compile time constant
EnumSensorFamily family = GetFimilyInRunTime(); // Run time variable
doTest1(family, proposed); // ok
doTest2<family>(proposed); // error;
doTest2<familyCompileTime >(proposed); // OK;
```

Comment: Yes it is known at compile time. Thanks for clarifying the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is also benefit on binary size, only the instantiated templates will be in the executable. 
If you have a huge switch, it could be significant on the exe size!