# Can I assign a member data pointer to a derived type?

Tags: c++, member-pointers

This is probably best shown with example code. The following fails to compile with g++:

```
struct Base {
};

struct Derived : public Base {
};

struct Container {
    Derived data_;
};

int main(void) {
    Base Container::*ptr = &Container::data_;
}
```

I get the following error: `invalid conversion from 'Derived Container::*' to Base Container::*'`.
Is this not allowed by the language? Is this a compiler bug? Am I using the wrong syntax?

Please help!

Some background as to why I'm trying to do this: I have several member data pieces that I want to use primarily as their derived types, but I want to be able to populate them through some common code. Data will be coming in an arbitrary order and have a string label that I would use to select the appropriate member data to populate. I was planning on creating a `std::map<std::string, Base Container::*>` to assign data to each member through a common interface. I'd like to avoid have a giant `if else` construct to find the right member data.

Comment: Maybe it's just your example, but in gerenal, you should not be implementing your own containers.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely this is a compiler bug.

Did you try to compile the example you posted? In main(), "&Container::data_" is not actually an instance, you don't have an object for "Container".

Comment: General comment to would be answerers: please learn about member pointer before answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a compiler bug, you can't do that. (But you can assign a Base::* to a Derived::*).

I don't see any good reason for the limitation (excepted that to handle the case of multiple inheritance, that would complicate even more the representation of a member pointer).

Comment: I see a perfectly good reason for the limitation -- it's not a `Base`!

Comment: @John, you can assign a Derived* to a Base* but not a Derived Foo::* to a Base Foo::*.  I don't see any reason other than implementation complexity. (I see good reasons not to allow to assign a Foo Derived::* to a Foo Base::*. And you can assign a Foo Base::* to a Foo Derived::*).

Answer (score 1):

Pointers to members in C++ are not *really* pointers but more like *offsets* to given member and are specific to the type, so what you are trying to do is not really supported.

Here's a decent discussion here on Stackoverflow [C++: Pointer to class data member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member).

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of fairly complex, some not-well-explained, and a few flat wrong answers in this thread.

But the problem, it seems to me, is that there simply isn't a `Base` member within `Container` -- there is a `Derived` member.  You can't do this:

```
Base Container::*ptr = &Container::data_;
```

...for the same reason you can't do this:

```
int a;
long* pl = &a;
```

In the second example, the object isn't a `long`, it's an `int`.  Similarly, in the first example the object isn't a `Base`, it's a `Derived`.

As a possibly tangential point, it seems to me like what you really want to do is have `Base` be an abstract class, and have `Container` have a `Base*` rather than a `Derived` member.

Comment: I don't see how your `int` vs. `long` analogy holds; by that reasoning, wouldn't that disallow `Base* b = &derived` too?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write:

```
Base* ptr = &container.data_;
```

but `container` has to be an instance of `Container`, so you have to create one variable of that type somewhere.

Comment: As far I as understand the question, the OP need pointers to member for its design.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert C::*A to C::*B even if there is a conversion possible between A and B.

However, you can do [this](http://ideone.com/DKvzy):

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Base::foo()\n"; }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "Derived::foo()\n"; }
};

struct Bar
{
    Base* x;

    Bar() : x(new Derived) {}
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    Base* Bar::*p = &Bar::x;
    (b.*p)->foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to `static_cast` to do this conversion as seen in 5.3.9/9. This reason for this is that it acts as a `static_cast` from parent object pointer to child object pointer would. In other words, putting a pointer to a derived member into a pointer-to-parent-member would allow you to possibly access a non-existent derived member from a parent object or pointer. If the standard allowed this automatically it would be easy to mess up and try to access a child member on a class that isn't of the appropriate child type (that contains said member).

Without more information it sounds like you need a different/better constructor/set interface in your `Base` class rather than trying to use pointers-to-member here.

Comment: Could you elaborate (possibly with an example) how automatically converting a `Derived Container::*` member to `Base Container::*` member could be unsafe?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want  is a 'container', ie a struct which just has pointers:

```
struct Container{
    Base* derivedAdata_;
    Base* derivedBdata_;
    ...
};
```

Now each of the members you know to be of a specific type (ie DerivedA, DerivedB etc) so you can down-cast them later.

But first you are receiving data (in arbitrary order), but with a string name, so you should have a map:

```
std::map<std::string, Base* Container::*>
```

And you must have already populated the map:

```
myMap["DerivedA"] = &Container::derivedAdata;
...
```

Now data arrives and you start populating the container:

```
instance.*(myMap[key]) = factory(key, data);
```

`myMap[key]` picks the right member of the container and `factory(key,data)` creates instances.

*btw you could just have a map as your container anyway:`std::map<std::string, Base*>`*

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the original issue, you can do this using pointer to functions, instead of introducing base classes.

```
class Container {
public:
  void set(std::string const& label, std::string const& value);

  void setName(std::string const& value) { _name = value; }
  void setAge(std::string const& age) {
    _age = boost::lexical_cast<size_t>(age);
  }

private:
  std::string _name;
  size_t _age;
};
```

How to implement `set` then ?

```
// container.cpp
typedef void (Container::*SetterType)(std::string const&);
typedef std::map<std::string, SetterType> SettersMapType;

SettersMapType SettersMap =
  boost::assign::map_list_of("name", &Container::setName)
                            ("age", &Container::setAge);

void Container::set(std::string const& label, std::string const& value) {
  SettersMapType::const_iterator it = SettersMap.find(label);
  if (it == SettersMap.end()) { throw UnknownLabel(label); }

  SetterType setter = it->second;
  (this->*setter)(value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct Container {
   Derived data_; 
};  

int main(void) 
{
   Base Container::*ptr = &Container::data_;
}
```

The first problem is that `Container` doesn't have a member called `ptr`

```
Container container_object;
Base *ptr = container_object.data_;
```

Would work. Note that there needs to be a container object to create the data_ member and it would need to be made public.

The alternative would be for derived::data_ to be a static member.

Comment: You're completely missing the point.  This question is asking about pointer-to-members.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member