# What does the "&SomeStruct::member" mean in C++ where "SomeStruct" is a struct and "member" is its member?

Tags: c++, types

Say `SomeStruct` is defined as:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    int member;
};
```

What does these means?

1. `&SomeStruct::member`
2. `int SomeStruct::*`

I encounter this, tried to output its type info but still cannot figure out the meaning.  Below is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
struct SomeStruct {
    int member;
};


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  cout << typeid(&SomeStruct::member).name() << endl;
  cout << typeid(int SomeStruct::*).name() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled by `i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)` on my MBP,  the output is:

```
M10SomeStructi
M10SomeStructi
```

Comment: It means [pointer to member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int SomeStruct::*` is called a "pointer to member", in this case, a pointer to a member of `SomeStruct`.  This is *NOT* strictly a pointer to a member function (although this is the most common use of this syntax).

`&SomeStruct::member` is a reference to the `member` member of `SomeStruct`.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member)

If you'd like some more complete information on the topic, [here's a decent article on the topic](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=142).

And, the obligatory section on the topic in the [C++ FAQ lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is the syntax for a pointer to a member function/data member.

`int SomeStruct::*` is the type of the pointer (pointer to an `int` data member of `SomeStruct`.

`&SomeStruct::member` yields a pointer of the above type.