# Understanding Pointer-to-Member operators

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, dereference, pointer-to-member

I copied this program from a c++ practice book. What's going on behind the scenes?

The expected output is:

> sum=30 sum=70

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class M
{
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    void set_xy(int a, int b)
    {
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    friend int sum(M m);
};

int sum (M m);
//so far so good, problem begins from here. what's happening after here?
{                               
    int M ::*px = &M ::x;
    int M ::*py = &M ::y;
    M *pm =&m;
    int s= m.*px+ pm->*py;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    M n;
    void (M :: *pf)(int, int) = &M ::set_xy;
    (n.*pf)(10, 20);
    cout <<"sum=" << sum(n) << endl;

    M *op= &n;
    (op-> *pf)(30,40);
    cout << "sum=" << sum(n)<< endl;

    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "->*" is one operator, instead of two. So They cannot be separated. You CANNOT write "-> *".

Comment: that problem is solved. can someone explain it's working please ?

Comment: Removing the tag "visual-studio", as it's not a problem specific to the compiler

Comment: cin.ignore();
getchar(); are commands for visual studio.

Comment: @jeet.mg, Yes commands are for VS, but not the compiler error problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of **extra whitespace** at `op-> *pf`:

```
 (op->*pf)(30,40);  // ok
```

I think @fefe has probably said the reason in comment. `->*` is a single operator, similar to `.*`. So, if those 2 are separated, then it will result in different syntax, which gives compiler error.

Comment: i read somewhere that c++ does not bothers about white spaces. let's try if it works.

Comment: @jeet.mg: the operator is `->*`. You can't put spaces anywhere you like (like `dele te` isn't the same as `delete`)

Comment: that problem is solved. can someone explain it's working please ?

Comment: @jeet.mg, that's a different question. You may have to 1st look at your code and if not understandable then you can post another question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Pointer to class data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member). And for the error, ->* is an operator, you can't put a space between them.

Answer (score 1):

[iammilind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514235/iammilind) bet me to the error; `op-> *pf` must be changed so that you have `->*` together as a single operator - a [pointer to member operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr205.htm) (couldn't find a better link). The whitespace in `op ->* pf` is perfectly valid.

That's the same for something like `i++`; `++` is a single operator and will cause an error if you try and have `i+ +`.

Now for what it's doing. The example is of a *pointer to a member* function. `pf` is being declared as a member function of `class M`, that takes two `int` arguments with a `void` return type. It's being initialized to point to the `M::set_xy` function.

Inside `main`:

- `n` is of type `M`, therefore in order to use `pf` to call `set_xy` of `n` you'd use the `.*` operator: `(n.*pf)(10, 20);`. That's equivalent to `n.set_xy(10, 20);`.
- Since `op` is of type `M*` (a pointer to an `M` object), you'll need to use the `->*` operator and call the function pointed to by `pf` as: `(op->*pf)(30, 40);`, which is equivalent to `op->set_xy(30, 40);`

Inside `sum`:

- The examples are simply of pointers to member/instance variables, as opposed to member functions. It's simply demonstrating how you would add together `m.x` and `m.y` using those types of pointers.