# Working example of accessing non-static member from static method

Tags: c++, class, pointers, static, non-static

I was studying [ns-3 tutorial](http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.13/tutorial/singlehtml/index.html#example-code). I cannot understand the following code snippet:

```
class MyObject : public Object
{
public:
  static TypeId GetTypeId (void)
  {
    static TypeId tid = TypeId ("MyObject")
       .SetParent (Object::GetTypeId ())
       .AddConstructor<MyObject> ()
       .AddTraceSource ("MyInteger",
                     "An integer value to trace.",
                      MakeTraceSourceAccessor (&MyObject::m_myInt))
       ;
     return tid;
  }

  MyObject () {}
  TracedValue<int32_t> m_myInt;
};
```

As I understand,  MyObject::m_myInt is an access to non-static class member m_myInt from static method and & takes address of this member. This code is successfully compiled and executed. How can it be possible? What instance of class does the static method use?

Comment: This is actually a pointer to member (not a pointer to an instance's member).  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/670734/1272627);  It has some good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers to members can be pointers to either member methods or member variables and do not need an instance of a class to be declared or assigned.  This does not mean you can do much without an instance, however.  You still need an instance to use them.  Consider the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    void SomeMethod();
    int someVar;
};

void (A::*pSomeMethod)() = &A::SomeMethod; //Declares a member pointer to method and assigns
int A::*pSomeVar = &A::someVar; //Declares a member pointer to int variable and assigns

A a; //Defines an instance
(a.*pSomeMethod)(); //Uses an instance with the pSomeMethod member pointer.
int var = (a.*pSomeVar); //Uses an instance with the pSomeVar member pointer.
```

It is possible, and it allows for some pretty cool stuff.