# use of pointer-to-member operators?

Tags: c++

I have come across the following code but not able to understand what is the importance of the following concept . Please help .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class cl 
{

public:
    cl(int i) { val=i; }
    int val;
    int double_val() { return val+val; }

};

int main()
{
    int cl::*data; // data member pointer
    int (cl::*func)(); // function member pointer
    cl ob1(1), ob2(2); // create objects
    cl *p1, *p2;
    p1 = &ob1; // access objects through a pointer
    p2 = &ob2;
    data = &cl::val; // get offset of val
    func = &cl::double_val; // get offset of double_val()
    cout << "Here are values: ";
    cout << p1->*data << " " << p2->*data << "\n";
    cout << "Here they are doubled: ";

    cout << (p1->*func)() << " ";
    cout << (p2->*func)() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which concept???? Please clearly state your question and then you will hopefully receive suitable answers.

Comment: The concept is to call a method by address. Please consider reading some book.

Comment: I think this Question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member

Comment: @OAOD :pointer-to-member operators concept ..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers-to-members are a special gadget in C++ that tell only tell you about a which member of a *class* you want without pertaining to any *object*. You need to combine a pointer-to-member with an object instance in order to obtain an actual member, whether it be a data or a function member.

Think of pointers-to-member as "offsets". Also, remember that pointers-to-member are *not* pointers!

We can rewrite your code to make it a bit clearer:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    double f(int, int);
    double g(int, int);
};

int main()
{
    int Foo::*ptm = &Foo::a;
    double (Foo::*ptmf)(int, int) = &Foo::f;

    Foo x, y, z;

    int numbers[] = { x.*ptm, y.*ptm, z.*ptm }; // array of Foo::a's

    ptm = &Foo::b;                              // reseat the PTM

    int more[] = { x.*ptm, y.*ptm, z.*ptm };    // array of Foo::b's


    double yetmore[] = { (x.*ptmf)(1,2), (y.*ptmf)(1,2) };

    ptmf = &Foo::g;

    double evenmore[] = { (x.*ptmf)(1,2), (y.*ptmf)(1,2) };
}
```

Note how we're using the pointers-to-member to refer only to the *class* member, and we can use that to get the same *relative* class member out of different *objects*.

(By contrast, we can also form a real pointer to an actual *object* member: `int * p = &x.a;`. That's because the member-`int` is actually an integer. But we cannot do anything analogous for member *functions*, because member functions are not functions (e.g. you cannot call them).)

Make sure you understand the difference between classes and objects, and this should become very clear!