# C++ compile error c2664 ZeroMemory

Tags: c++

Why does this `ZeroMemory(&socketAddress, sizeof(Connection::socketAddress));` work, but this doesn't?

```
ZeroMemory(&Connection::socketAddress, sizeof(Connection::socketAddress));
```

I get this error: `error C2664: 'memset' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'sockaddr_in Connection::* ' to 'void *'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&Connection::socketAddress` is a member pointer. It's not itself a pointer, but a way to get a pointer to a particular member of a class given a pointer to that class. `ZeroMemory` can't accept it because it doesn't actually point to any real memory; it needs more information (a pointer to the instance of the class containing the member) before it can actually get a real pointer.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/670734) for more information about member pointers.