# Assign values based on variable name in a string

Tags: c++

Weird question and hard to word but lets say I have a 2 files that have a string of what double variables will appear in the file at the top and then the corresponding double variables, something like:

File1 =

```
A B C D E
1.2 3.4 4.5 5.6 7.8
```

File2=

```
B D E
9.8 7.6 5.4
```

and I have a struct of doubles

```
struct numb{
double A,B,C,D,E};
```

is it possible to read in the string in file 1 (A B C D E) and whatever the first value in the string is (A) assign it to the corresponding struct value numb.A.

So then the next file it will read in the first value of the string (B) and assign it to numb.B.
I realize this is possible with a bunch of if statements but I was wondering if there is an easier way. The hardest part is the string of variables will always be some combination of A,B,C,D,E. I am programming in C++ VS10

Comment: If A B C etc. are actually configuration values I would advice you to write a generic useable class being able to handle arbitrary strings/names. Examples: http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Util.AbstractConfiguration.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Answer (score 2):

You can create a map with the string to parse as the key, and a [pointer to member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member) of the corresponding attribute of your structure as the value.

```
std::map<std::string, double numb::*> mapLetterToCorrespondingAttribute;
```

Then parse your file and assign the value to the corresponding member pointed to by the value in your map corresponding to the key being the letter you parsed.

Read this multiple times before you say you don't understand :D

Comment: A nice addition: Expose this map in your class or provide a method which uses this map for the implementation (even better).

Answer (score 0):

A `switch` is probably the easiest way to do this.

```
void set_member(numb &n, char member, double value)
{
    switch (member) {
      case 'A':
        n.A = value;
        break;
      case 'B':
        n.B = value;
        break;
      // etc.
      default:
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array of double in `struct numb`.

```
struct numb {
    void setValue(char label, double val) { value[label-'A'] = val; }
    double getValue(char label) const { return value[label-'A']; }
    double value[5]; 
};
```

Then, you could perform:

```
numb n;
n.setValue('A', 1.2);
double A = n.getValue('A');
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the two lines into `std::vector<std::string>` and then put them into a map in pairs:

```
std::vector<std::string> vars;    // the split up first line
std::vector<std::string> values;  // split up second line

std::map<std::string, double> mapping;
for (int i = 0; i < vars.size(); ++i) {
    mapping.insert(std::make_pair(vars[i], boost::lexical_cast<double>(values[i]));
}
```

If you pre-populate the map `mapping` with sensible default values, this should be quite simple. Also, you can substitute the call to `boost::lexical_cast<double>` with any conversion method you like.