# How to pass the address of a field of a class in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to work out how to do this, so I have an example class called myClass:

```
//In myClass.h
Class myClass
{
    private:

    GLuint id;
};

//In myClass.cpp, in one of the functions
glGenBuffers(1, &myClass::id);
```

So glGenBuffers wants the address of a GLuint to assign the ID of the buffer to but when I try to do this I get the compilation error:

Cannot convert 'GLuint myClass::*' to 'GLuint*' in argument passing

Comment: You need to make an instance of the class first, otherwise the member doesn't even exist.

Comment: Pointers to members are completely different types than other pointers.

Comment: But this call is within the class itself I do create an instance of this class in another part of my project but this produces an error on compile?

Comment: Than you should pass `&(this->id)`

Comment: @StoryTeller: `&id` is enough, I think.

Comment: @TonyK, you are right of course. I was just trying to emphasize that the `id` must belong to an object.

Comment: @StoryTeller: But if you're going to put it in parentheses anyway (which is redundant in your case), you might as well stick with the original `&(myClass::id)`, which compiles without errors -- see my answer for more info.

Comment: @TonyK, I add parenthesis for my own and possibly others' readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> //In myClass.cpp, in one of the functions

If by this you mean in one of `myClass`'s non-`static` member functions, then you can simply:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &id);
```

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't `&myClass::id` work? See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could be forgiven for expecting this to work, if called from within a non-static member function of `myClass`. For instance, this works:

```
GLuint x = myClass::id;
```

More mysteriously, this works too:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &(myClass::id));
```

Similarly:

```
GLuint *p = &myClass::id;   // Doesn't work!
GLuint *p = &(myClass::id); // Works!
```

As John Dibling wrote, in general the solution is simply to omit the scope qualifier:

```
GLuint x = id;
glGenBuffers(1, &id);
```

But this won't work if you are trying to access a member in a base class that has the same name. So what is the difference between `&myClass::id` and `&(myClass::id)`? I wish I could tell you, but I can't figure it out! The scope operator `::` has the highest precedence of all the C++ operators, so I would expect them to be equivalent. Can anybody put me right?

**Edited to add:** OK, it all makes some kind of sense. In the draft standard N3337 for C++0x, it says:

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. The
>   operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*. If the operand is a
>   *qualified-id* naming a non-static member `m` of some class `C` with type `T`, the result has type “pointer to member of class `C` of type
>   `T`” and is a prvalue designating `C::m`. Otherwise...

Then you go and look up what a *qualified_id* is, and it turns out that if you put it in parentheses, it's not a *qualified_id* any more. Which explains everything.

Comment: There's nothing mysterious here. Scope resolution is the tool used when ambiguity occurs. If `myClass` had a base class with its own `id` member, you'd have to use scope resolution. Either `&this->myClass::id` (see why `this->` is useful :P) or simply `&(myClass::id)`.

Comment: @StoryTeller: So why do you need the parentheses? I am still searching through the C++ standard document, looking for a paragraph about the special case `&<classname>::<membername>`. I'll let you know if I find it!

Comment: The ones that don't work are returning a pointer to member, there's a question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member). It seems like a very confusing syntax though!

Comment: Because without them you get a pointer to member type. That's the syntax, for all its convoluted glory

Comment: `myClass::id` is a _qualified-id_, `(myClass::id)` is a _primary-expression_. Similar to the difference between `decltype(a)` and `decltype((a))`.

Comment: `5.3.1.3` _If the operand is a qualified-id naming a non-static member m of some class C with type T, the result has
type "pointer to member of class C of type T"... if the type of
the expression is T, the result has type "pointer to T"..._ `5.3.1.4` _A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit
& is used and its operand is a qualified-id not enclosed in parentheses._

Comment: @Oktalist: We agree exactly! Thank you for confirming my diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to understand the difference between a class and an object. 
A class is a blueprint, an object is an instance of a class - ie an actual thing that you can manipulate. (similar to a cookie cutter and a cookie - the cutter just provides the shape the cookie will be, once you've cut one, or two, or many cookies out of a big heap of dough)

So.. you either have to instantiate an object to access the id, or you have to specify that there is a single 'global' id by using the static keyword.

Comment: The word "template" can be misleading considering templates in C++ are their own thing.

Comment: A member does not have to be `public` in order to pass its address as a function parameter.  Also, "blueprint" might be netter (less confusing) than "template".

Comment: @JohnDibling thanks, I would have finished my answer - but work called :(