# Protected member function address in derived class is not accessible

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected, pointer-to-member

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
protected:
    void foo()
    {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void bar()
    {
       std::cout << (&A::foo) << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.bar();
}
```

Here I am trying to get address of protected member function of base class. I am getting this error.

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void B::bar()’:
main.cpp:5: error: ‘void A::foo()’ is protected
main.cpp:13: error: within this context
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Changing foo to public works. Also printing `&B::foo` works. Can you please explain why we can't get address of protected member function of base class?

Comment: Good question. Seems like a future correction!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`B` is allowed to access protected members of `A` as long as the access is performed through an object of type `B`. In your example you're trying to access `foo` through `A`, and in that context it is irrelevant whether `B` derives from `A` or not.

From N3337, *§11.4/1 **[class.protected]***

> An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause 11 is applied when a non-static data member or non-static member function is a protected member of its naming class (11.2) As described 
>   earlier, **access to a protected member is granted because the reference occurs in a friend or member of some class `C`. If the access is to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), the *nested-name-specifier* shall denote `C` or a
>   class derived from `C`**. All other accesses involve a (possibly implicit) object expression (5.2.5). In this case, the class of the object expression shall be `C` or a class derived from `C`. [*Example:*
>
> ```
>  class B {
>  protected:
>    int i;
>    static int j;
>  };
>  class D1 : public B {
>  };
>  class D2 : public B {
>    friend void fr(B*,D1*,D2*);
>    void mem(B*,D1*);
>  };
>  // ...
>  void D2::mem(B* pb, D1* p1) {
>    // ...
>    int B::* pmi_B = &B::i; // ill-formed
>    int B::* pmi_B2 = &D2::i; // OK
>    // ...
>  }
>  // ...
> ```
>
> *—end example*]

Your example is very similar to the code in `D2::mem`, which shows that trying to form a pointer to a protected member through `B` instead of `D2` is ill-formed.

Comment: Can someone explain the syntax `int B::* pmi_B`? Are `pmi_B` and `pmi_B2` int values or are they pointers? Why do you called `B::` before the asterisk?

Comment: @Sterling It's a [pointer to data member of class B](http://stackoverflow.com/a/670744/241631)

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found the answer. If we could get pointer of member function we can call it for other objects of type `A` (not `this`) which is not allowed.

It is not allowed to call protected member function in derived classes for objects other than `this`. Getting pointer would violent that.

We can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
protected:
    void foo()
    {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void bar()
    {
        void (A::*fptr)() = &A::foo;

        A obj;
        (obj.*fptr)();

        // obj.foo(); //this is not compiled too.    
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.bar();
}
```

Comment: We can already do that, since it's a protected member and derived class is allowed to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious and tried the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    void foo()
    {
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void bar()
    {
       printf("%p\n", (&A::foo));
       printf("%p\n", (&B::foo));
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.bar();
}
```

Actually, I see that `&A::foo` == `&B::foo`, so for protected member of base class you can use derived class member to take address. I suppose in case of virtual functions this will not work

Comment: Your example doesn't have protected members. Change `public` to `protected` in `A` and it no longer compiles. So, your statement *you can use derived class member to take address* is wrong.