# What does ::* mean in C++?

Tags: c++

What does

```
 private:
    BOOL (LASreader::*read_simple)();
```

mean?

It's from LAStools, in [lasreader.hpp](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/blob/master/LASlib/inc/lasreader.hpp#L132-L133)

`BOOL` is a `typedef bool` (from [mydefs.hpp](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/blob/master/LASzip/src/mydefs.hpp#L59)), but I don't know what this line is declaring, specifically the `::*` (double colon asterisk), and that it looks like a function call.

Comment: pointer to member.

Comment: Like an alias to a method?  Because there's no member (variable nor method) named `read_simple` on this class.  The CPP for this header does use a variable named `read_simple`, but I don't see any declaration for it.  And this class doesn't extend anything.. maybe I'm just missing something

Comment: related post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a [pointer to member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions). Specifically, `read_simple` is a pointer to a member function of class `LASreader` that takes zero arguments and returns a `BOOL`.

From the example in the cppreference:

```
struct C {
    void f(int n) { std::cout << n << '\n'; }
};
int main()
{
    void (C::*p)(int) = &C::f; // p points at member f of class C
    C c;
    (c.*p)(1); // prints 1
    C* cptr = &c;
    (cptr->*p)(2); // prints 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now I just have to figure out why they're doing this. :)  That member points at a pure virtual member function.

Comment: @Matt Nothing wrong with that. When you call it with an instance, it'll still go through the same virtual dispatch process.

Answer (score 4):

```
BOOL (LASreader::*read_simple)();
```

`read_simple` is a pointer to a member function of class `LASreader` that takes no arguments and returns a `BOOL`.