# What does C::* mean in typename argument

Tags: c++, templates

I know there is a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767243/what-does-mean-in-c)

My question is slightly different from that,
what does it mean When c::* appears in the template parameter,

```cpp
template <typename C>
static yes& f(typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<decltype(static_cast<typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>(&C::begin)),
    typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>::value>::type*);
```

from [here](https://github.com/louisdx/cxx-prettyprint/blob/master/prettyprint.hpp#L54)

Can someone explain what this piece of code means，especially this one

> typename C::const_iterator(C::*)()

Comment: There's no difference. It's still a pointer to member function.

Comment: that's not a complete statement. But C::* means same,  pointer to member declarator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO that's awfully constructed statement over there, it's unreadable. But it can be "disassembled" hierarchically:

```
template <typename C>
static yes & f (
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<
            decltype(
                static_cast<
                     typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const
                >(&C::begin)
            ),
            typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const
        >::value
    >::type *
);
```

It declares a template with class parameter C of function `f` that returns  `yes&`.

The function instance will have a parameter of type `void*` if typename `C::const_iterator(C::*)() const` and the type of result of cast of `&C::begin` to `C::const_iterator(C::*)() const` are same, otherwise the template won't produce legal instance due to SFINAE, because `std::enable_if<>::type` won't be declared (`std::enable_if<expr>::type` defaults to `void` if `expr` is true)

`typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const` is  a pointer to member of class C with signature similar to
`C::const_iterator name () const`, i.e. it returns `C::const_iterator`, takes no parameters, and is a const member. In standard prior to C++20 you have to use `typename` if declaration depends on template parameter, it seems that requirement is proposed to be lifted in latest standard.

`static_cast<typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>` is there likely to protect from case when `C::begin` is an overloaded function member, it would choose the proper overload.

Comment: Thank you, I am used to Range-based for loop, I almost forget that begin is a function>_<

Comment: @鱼门国主 ranged loops are usable only if you don't invalidate iterators of collection. E.g. if you try to remove element, you can't replace current iterator value (and now invalid after element it was pointing to was removed) with new one  returned.

Answer (score 0):

> what does it mean When c::* appears

Outside of context, it is part of syntax for a pointer to member of `c`.

When put in context: `C::const_iterator(C::*)() const` type is pointer to const qualified member function of `C` that returns `C::const_iterator` and has empty parameter list.