# Assigning a non-static function to a variable in c++

Tags: c++

I was trying to assign a non-static function to a variable in C++.
I have two functions, which are `onMessageReceived` and `enableCommand`.
Here are definitions:

NetworkUtil.h:

```
class NetworkUtil{
public:
    std::function<void(char* message)> onMessageReceived;
    void enableCommand(char* cmd);
private:
// some private variables
}
```

NetworkUtil.cpp:

```
void NetworkUtil::enableCommand(char* cmd) {
    if (strcmp(cmd, "INIT_ACK") == 0){
        mCreateEnabled = true;
    }
    else if (strcmp(cmd, "START_ACK")){
        mStartEnabled = true;

    }
    else{
        std::cerr << "Unknown Command: " << cmd << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here is a program that assigns a function to a variable:

```
void NetworkUtil::onMessage(WebSocket* ws, const WebSocket::Data &data)
{
// not working
    onMessageReceived = &(NetworkUtil::enableCommand);
// not working either
    onMessageReceived = std::bind(&NetworkUtil::enableCommand, data.bytes);
}
```

I tried both, but non of them are working. Can I get some advice on assigning a non-static function to a variable?

Comment: `std::bind(&NetworkUtil::enableCommand, this);` should work

Comment: `if (strcmp(cmd, "START_ACK"))`?? Did you mean to use `if (strcmp(cmd, "START_ACK") == 0)`?

Comment: Not up on my std::bind, but I doubt you need to take the address of the function. OK. Maybe you do. Quite surprised by this.

Comment: @cpplearner: `std::bind(&NetworkUtil::enableCommand, this);` does not work.

Comment: @R Sahu: Thank you for pointing out the logical error.

Comment: @cpplearner: Error Message: Term does not evaluate a function taking 1 arguments.

Comment: What is the type of onMessageReceived?

Comment: @ user4581301: It accepts two arguments, whose types are `Websocket*` and `data`. `data` is nothing but `struct` that contains `char*` type instance variable.

Comment: I think @cpplearner  almost had it. Give `std::bind(&NetworkUtil::enableCommand, this, data.bytes);` a spin, but I think this will get bind right and give a different error because you can't stuff bind into whatever onMessageReceived is.

Comment: @user4581301 It worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: By the way, `onMessageReceived`  takes one input, which is `char*`. Sorry for misreading your question.

Comment: No worries. I wasn't reading well. Your Question answered my question. The trick is NetworkUtil::enableCommand is a class member so it has `NetworkUtil * this` as a hidden extra param.

Comment: @user4581301 I wish to learn more about this `std::bind` and how it works and when should it be used. Any practical example or what is happening wrong in this case that normal assignment is not working properly. An answer with this explanation will be really helpful.

Comment: @VinayShukla I think you'll find your answer in the comment just above yours.

Comment: @user4581301 yes Indeed, Thanks !!!

Comment: I think this is a "pointer to member" issue e.g.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this:

```
onMessageReceived = std::bind(&NetworkUtil::enableCommand, this, _1);
```

Comment: may need `using std::placeholders;`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `std::function` (hence C++11 or later), I assume you can give [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) a try:

```
// Create a local variable for capturing purposes.
// You must make sure the source data is never outlived by the callback
// to avoid the "use after free" scenario.
auto bytes = data.bytes;
onMessageReceived = [=](char * message) { this->enableCommand(bytes); };
```

`=` means to capture everything *actually used* by the closure by value (including the value of the `this` pointer), and due to use of [type erasure](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/oz18T05o/) you can assign it to a signature-compatible `std::function`.