# What does &Type::variable mean?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    struct Bob
    {
        int a;
    };

    &Bob::a;
}
```

What does `&Bob::a` mean? Bob is a type and not an instance, so what is it taking the address of?

Comment: It creates a [pointer to member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member) `a` of type `Bob`.

Comment: The key here is that the `&` is _not_ applied to `Bob`, but instead to the whole `Bob::a` name.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit However if one tries to use parentheses `&(Bob::a)`, it does not work.

Comment: @AlexD: Not sure I get your point. I never claimed that it would. But the OP thought this was [pseudocode] `(&Bob)::a`, which is why he could not work out what is going on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Your remark was that `&` applies to the whole thing, to `Bob::a`. To make it clear, one can try placing parenthesis around. However `&(Bob::a)` would not work.

Comment: @AlexD: Parentheses have absolutely nothing to do with this. I don't know why you brought them up.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm just trying to say that after reading your comment someone could place parentheses `&(Bob::a)` to make it clear in the code that `&` applies to `Bob::a`, not just to `Bob`. And it would not work. Never mind :).

Comment: @AlexD: Such a person would be silly. Would they also hear "in `int*`, the `*` modifies the `int`" and automatically expect `(int)*` to be a valid type?

Answer (score 2):

It is a pointer to a member of class. According to the standard (N4296, 5.3.1):

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*.
>   If the operand is a *qualified-id* naming a non-static or variant member `m` of some class `C` with type `T`,
>   the result has type “pointer to member of class `C` of type `T`” and is a prvalue designating `C::m`.