# Understanding C++ syntax in a DLL class

Tags: c++, dll, function-pointers, dll-injection

I try to understand somecode, which could be summarized into something like this:

```
class FooClass {
    public:
        void Foo();
        static void (FooClass::*Foo_Original)();
};

void (FooClass::* FooClass::Foo_Original)() = 0;
void FooClass::Foo() {
    (this->*Foo_Original)();
}
```

This is part of a more complex dll solution in Visual Studio. From debugger I found that method `Foo()` is called from some other dll. Can someone explain what this syntax means? What is it supposed to do?

That's not duplicate to this one.
[C++: Pointer to class data member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member)
Please, be more thoughtful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FooClass` exposes a member function `Foo()` and a static pointer to a member function.  The pointer is called `Foo_Original`.

As it is a static pointer, it must be initialised, here with 0 (aka nullptr).

The function `Foo()` just calls the function that is pointed to by `Foo_Original`.  Of course, this will do other thing as U.B, only if the pointer was initialized somewhere to a member function.

Example:

```
class FooClass {
public:
    void Foo();
    static void (FooClass::*Foo_Original)();
    // additional member functions for the demo:
    void Bar()  { std::cout << "Bar was called" << std::endl; }
    void Goo()  { std::cout << "Goo was called" << std::endl; }
};
int main()
{
    FooClass f; 
    // f.Foo(); ==> U.B, as Foo_Original is still 0 
    f.Foo_Original = &FooClass::Bar;
    f.Foo(); 
    f.Foo_Original = &FooClass::Goo;
    f.Foo();
}
```

*P.S.: I don't know how this relates to dll and dll injection in your specific case, but I could imagine that your FooClass loads dynamically some DLLs and offers a standardized interface for them.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't use them much, but this looks like it's declaring a ptr-to-a-FooClass-member-function that takes zero args and 'returns' void.  I'm not sure if it's declaring a static pointer though, or a pointer-to-a-static-member-function).

Comment: Your hesitation is understandable (and this alone would justify an upvote of the original question) ! It's a static pointer to a non static member function.  There would be no `FooClass::*` for a static function.  [This FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)  should clarify your doubt :-)