# C++ `int* class::*member = NULL` compiles, why?

Tags: c++

I cannot figure out how this compiles. It seems like it should not, and if I use a value other than NULL in the constructor it will not.

```
#include <stdio.h>


class MyClass{
    private:
        int *first;
    public:
        MyClass();
};

MyClass::MyClass(){

    int whatever = 42;
    //int* MyClass::*first = &whatever;//This does not compile
    int* MyClass::*first = NULL;//This compiles
}

int main(){

    MyClass doSomething;
    return 1;
}
```

It seems that generally the `type Class::member = value` syntax is used for static vars, which this is not.

Also, there is an asterisk before the member name, which confuses things even more.

If I switch the lines to the one that is commented out, the compiler complains, as expected.

```
error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int* MyClass::*’ in initialization
```

While I did expect an error, I have no idea what the type `int* MyClass::*` is. Or how it could be used.

Comment: I am not sure but I suspect you have created a pointer to member variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member

Comment: try `int *MyClass::*first = &MyClass::first;`. Giving it a different name might be a bit less confusing.

Comment: Where is the _static vars_ ?

Comment: @NeilKirk Yeah, I think you're right. I got this from a friend trying to grade a students code, and it was just weird that it compiled at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pointer to data member. You cannot initialize it with an ordinary pointer, that is why the commented out expression does not compile.