# What does it mean to have three elements in typedef in C++?

Tags: c++

I know from c++ primer that we can use typedef in the following ways:

```
typedef int mytype;
typedef int *mytype;
```

However, the following code also compiles, and it seems to create a new type "rt", I am curious what is the type of rt, and what are common uses of this kind of typedef?

```
class A{
public:
    int c;
};
typedef int A::* rt;
```

Comment: Look up "pointer to member variable".

Answer (score 5):

It is not a "three elements typedef", it is a pointer to member variable typedef. You can find more information about pointer to member variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/670744/4745527).

In your precise case, it allows you to instantiate variables of type "rt" that will point to a precise member of type `int` of `A` class, and then use it to access this member on `A` instances.

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
    int c;
};
typedef int A::* rt;

int main() {
  A instance;
  rt member; // This is a pointer to A member.
  member = &A::c; // This pointer will point on c member of A class

  instance.c = 0;
  instance.*member += 2; // As member point on c, this code access to the c member.
  std::cout << instance.c << std::endl; // This will now output "2".
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pointer to member variable.
You define it with this syntax: `int A::* pointer;`, and initialize it `$A::c` and read it's value `instance.*pointer`.

`A instance;
int A::* pointer = &A::c;
instance.*pointer = 10;`

Actually it's an offset from beginning of the class that allow you to hold a pointer to `int` that is a member variable of class `A`.