# How to use C++11 std::is_member_object_pointer in type_traits?

Tags: c++11, type-traits

```
struct A { int x; };

int main() {
    int A::* pt = &A::x;
    return 0;
}
```

what does `int A::*` mean exactly? I have never seen C++ syntax like this.

Comment: You tried googling "member object pointer c++"?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Pointer to class data member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like other traits, you specify the template argument and use the `value` member.

```
std::is_member_object_pointer<decltype(pa) >::value
```

> what does `int A::*` mean exactly?

That is a type declaration of a member object pointer to an int member of the class A.