# Inheriting from Abstract Class in C++

Tags: c++, abstract-class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

enum Month
{
    jan = 1,
    feb,
    mar
};

class Show
{
public:
    virtual void Display() = 0;
};

class Date : public Show
{
private:
    Month m;
    int day;
    int year;
public:
    Date( Month mName, int dayName, int yearName )
    {
        m = mName;
        day = dayName;
        year = yearName;
    }
    void Display()
    {
        cout << this->m << endl;
    }
};

void displayData( void *data[] )
{
    Month m = *( reinterpret_cast<const Month*> ( data[ 0 ] ) );
    cout << m << endl;
}

int main( int argc, char**argv )
{
    Date d1( jan, 28, 2017 );
    void * data[ 1 ];
    data[ 0 ] = &d1;
    displayData( data );
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the correct value for Month m in the function void displayData but when I inherit the Date class from the abstract class Show, then I'm getting a garbage value for Month m. Can anyone tell me why is this happening ?

Comment: The derived class has a table of pointers to virtual functions that it seems is placed in the beginning of the class.

Comment: Not to mention the bad type cast is to something completely unrelated, so inheritance has nothing to do with this.  Did you want something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member ?  Or just use d1.m

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way around for this ?

Comment: Why bother defining all these types if you're going to strip them away with the `void*` casting? Surely `displayData` should at least take a `Show` parameter? Anyway, you're forcing it to interpret a `Date` as a `Month` so you will probably just get garbage.

Comment: In that data array I can have other objects of different class, so I'm casting it to void *. I'm forcing Date to interpret as Month so as to get the Month value and proceed further depending on the month value. Is there any other way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2):

You are reinterpret-casting a `Date` as a `Month`.  So, you are assuming that this is a safe conversion, but it isn't.  It happens to work purely by accident when the `Date` class is just plain data, but when you derive the `Date` class from `Show` then the structure of the class becomes more complicated, and the accident does not hold true anymore.

What is probably happening is that the first element in `Date` is now a pointer to the virtual method table of the class rather than the first member declared in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the void pointer. Use a base class like Show instead, like:

```
void displayData( Show *data[] )
{
    data[0]->Display();
}

int main( int argc, char**argv )
{
    Date d1( jan, 28, 2017 );
    Show* data[ 1 ];
    data[ 0 ] = &d1;
    displayData( data );
    return 0;
}
```

Else how you would devide the void pointers to their classes?