# c++ variadic templates fold expression

Tags: c++, templates

i m reading a book about templates.there's a piece of sample code using a fold expression to traverse a path in a binary tree using operator ->*:

```
// define binary tree structure and traverse helpers:
struct Node {
  int value;
  Node* left;
  Node* right;
  Node(int i=0) : value(i), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {
  }
  //...
};
auto left = &Node::left;
auto right = &Node::right;

// traverse tree, using fold expression:
template<typename T, typename... TP>
Node* traverse (T np, TP... paths) {
  return (np ->* ... ->* paths);      // np ->* paths1 ->* paths2 ...
}

int main()
{
  // init binary tree structure:
  Node* root = new Node{0};
  root->left = new Node{1};
  root->left->right = new Node{2};
  //...
  // traverse binary tree:
  Node* node = traverse(root, left, right);
  //...
}
```

i dont quite understand the line

```
auto left = &Node::left;
auto right = &Node::right;
```

as i used to think the :: operator apply to classes will only refer to its static member,maybe i'm wrong in this case,and i do know :: is scope resolution operator, it may refer to Node's left anyway even its not static ,  but why can it use & operator to get its address? actually, what i was considering, is this just an alias like

```
using left = &Node::left; // can't compile
```

only work if

```
auto left = &Node::left;
```

what's the result of auto? the explicit type of this expression?

note that: the global left and right are used here

```
Node* node = traverse(root, left, right);
```

which is the last line in main.

i 've tried to run it , it all works, but i don't quite get it,how does it work?

Comment: Google "pointer to member."

Comment: @Angew alright, thanks a lot.i was so confused.

Comment: Well, that's a really silly example. What's the name of the book?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `left` and `right` is

```
Node* Node::*left
```

a case of [pointer to class data member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member). You can imagine it encodes the offset of `left` *within the representation* of an unspecified instance of `Node`, rather than a fixed position in memory. It can only be dereferenced when this instance is provided,

```
node.*left
```

(giving a `Node*`) or in your case, where the root is a (normal) pointer itself,

```
root->*left.
```

This is what the line

```
return (np ->* ... ->* paths);
```

unfolds to.