# C++17 Tree Traversal with Fold Expressions

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, fold-expression

I'm looking at the same tree traversal example as [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880232/c-variadic-templates-fold-expression). My VS is not supporting C++17 to see Fold Expresion inner workings. I guess this line:

```
Node* node = traverse(root, left, right);
```

would only traverse the binary tree from the root to the first leaf node and return? Or is it a complete preorder traversal? 
How to implement **Pre- Post-** and **Inorder** traversals using Fold Expressions?

Comment: That `traverse` isn't actually a traversal. It follows the path `left, right` (or whatever you pass it) inside `root` and returns the `Node*` at that position. I might call it `index`.

Comment: Fold expressions are best used when there is a large number of operations whose order is fixed at compile time.  Trees are usually dynamic.  So I'm not sure what you want here.

Comment: Have you set your compiler to latest standard?