# What does `::*` (colon colon star) means in C++?

Tags: c++

There is a segment of code incomprehensible when my friend was reading [this hpp file](https://github.com/emil-e/rapidcheck/blob/69ae4f77f57ee29609d8eb66dace6724feaf64d1/include/rapidcheck/gen/Build.hpp#L12). Specifically,

- what does certain formation such as `A(B, C)`, `int(int, int)`, or in this case `T(Type::*)` means? I've already seen usages such as `std::function<int(int, int)>`, but still have no idea what `int(int, int)`, alone, means.
- what does `Type::*` mean? How can a asterisk mark follows `::` directly?

Comment: Is `Type` a namespace?

Comment: *"but still have no idea what `int(int, int)`, alone, means"* -- `int(int, int)` is the type of `int f(int, int)`. You should figure out what this declaration means (`f` is a function that takes two `int` arguments and returns an `int`).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member

Comment: @Dominique It is more likely to be a type name, I suppose.

Comment: @axiac So you mean `int(int, int)` is actually a type of function? I've never thought of that, because I've seen something like `int (*func)(int, int)`, i.e. function pointer types pretty much, but not the function types themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`::*` is used to declare a pointer to a member of a class. So in this case, it's pointing to a member of the template type called `Type`.

`std::function<int(int, int)>` is an `std::function` for holding a method that takes parameters of `(int, int)` and returns an integer result. (This is an example of the famously complicated C/C++ type declaration syntax.)