# How to Access Structure Members as Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to cin a value to the birthMonth variable in my structure. My understanding is that structure members are stored sequentially. If that is the case, I cannot find out why using the line

```
cin >> *((short*)((people) + sizeof(Person::name)));
```

does not store the input value into the structure element. Am I wrong about the members of a structure being stored sequentially?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Person {
    char name[15];
    short birthMonth;
};
int main() {
    Person people[2];
    cout << "Birth Month: ";
    cin >> *((short*)(people + sizeof(Person::name)));
    cout << people[0].birthMonth;
}
```

Sample Run:

```
Birth Month: 7
0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: What is the goal? You can't really do this and I don't understand what the purpose is

Comment: There might be padding between the members, especially if one member has an uneven size, like 15. Why not just `cin >> people[0].birthMonth;`? Also, `people + 15` moves 15 whole elements further in memory, not 15 bytes. Pointers are tricky!

Comment: @Unholy Sheep Honestly, I just wanted to practice using pointers. I am a student so I thought it would be cool to apply my (still growing) understanding of pointers to this program. Could you explain what is wrong about it? I get that it is type punning but it brought up an interesting question about how variables are stored within a structure that led to this.

Comment: @Bo Persson Ah yes I see that now. Even so, when I put person in parens to prevent the pointer arithmetic I get the same issue. So the explanation of padding would make sense. Thank you for the insight Bo Persson.

Comment: Also note that `(people + sizeof(Person::name))` gives you a pointer to a non-existent 16th element of your `people` array (and not a pointer to after the `name` member.

Comment: @UnholySheep I see that now. When I separate it like     ((people) + sizeof(Person::name)) the value is still not stored, but thank you.

Comment: It's the same with or without the extra parentheses.  You would need a cast to get a pointer after the `name` member: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(people) + sizeof(Person::name)`

Comment: @Miles Budneck I tried using reinterpret_cast in that way and same issue, but as many of the answers have pointed out the issue has to do with the alignment of the memory, padding, other things I am studying now. Thanks for the comment nonetheless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of memory alignment and padding, C++ actually doesn't give any guarantee that a struct's member is located according to the cumulative size of previous members. If you're trying to write to the first `Person`'s `birthMonth`, it's as simple as:

```
cin >> people[0].birthMonth;
```

EDIT: to actually address the question's title, if you want an `int*` pointer to a specific person's `birthMonth`, it's done using the address-of operator:

```
int* birthMonth_ptr = &people[0].birthMonth;
```

But if you want a pointer to *any* `Person`'s `birthMonth` member, you can use a [pointer-to-member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member):

```
// Note that no Person object is used when defining
int Person::*member_ptr = &Person::birthMonth;

// To use the pointer though, you need an object
int a_persons_birthdate = people[0].*member_ptr;
```

Also note that a pointer-to-member is typed differently from a regular pointer, and can't be cast to one.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why your code does not work, add a few lines to print couple of addresses.

```
short* ptr1 = (short*)(people + sizeof(Person::name));
short* ptr2 = &(people[0].birthMonth);
std::cout << "ptr1: " << ptr1 << ", ptr2: " << ptr2 << std::endl;
```

You will notice that due to alignment requirements, `ptr1` and `ptr2` are different.

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment.