# C++ what is &Class::MemberVariable?

Tags: c++, syntax, static, non-static

In C++, I think it's not allowed to use non-static member variable in static method. However, what does this syntax mean? It compiles and runs.

```
class Bar {
 public:
  static void print() {
    // What does &Bar::val_ mean???
    cout << &Bar::val_ << endl;
  }

 private:
  int val_ = 123;

};

int main()
{
    Bar::print();
    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/BkjHR1FE8

Comment: Please take several weeks to read a good [C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/), then some [C++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) then some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) then the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf). It would take dozen of pages and of hours to explain you what a [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) or an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(computer_science)) is. And C++ is a very complex programming language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/pointer-to-class-data-member

Comment: See https://norvig.com/21-days.html for more insights0

Comment: U're not using da variable but taking it's address (relative to the begin (first member) of da class).

Comment: @J.Doe Nope. There is no address for that variable since there's no object of type `Bar` anywhere.

Comment: @NikosC. simplified to fit in a comment on SO.

Comment: Please don't use unrelated language tags.

Comment: @NikosC. Thank you. Now it explains.