# What is the right initialization of array of pointers to members of the c++ 17 class?

Tags: c++, pointers, stm32

I'm using VS 2019 with VisualGDB extension for STM32F303VC device. I have a class `TlteCom` with array of pointers to members of the C++ 17 class. Here it is:

```
class TlteCom
 {
  public:
   volatile uint16_t number=0;
   volatile uint16_t paramNumber=0;
   volatile char param1[20];
   volatile char param2[20];
   volatile char param3[8];

   constexpr static uint8_t paramCount = 3;
   volatile char *const paramlist[paramCount] = {(volatile char *)param1, (volatile char *)param2, 
                                                 (volatile char*)param3};
   volatile uint16_t paramlength[paramCount] = { 0, 0, 0 };
 };
```

I create the object of the class as global variable as follows: `TlteCom com;`

I don't understand why `com.paramlist` members are all zero. if I create object of the `TlteCom` class on stack in `main()` function everything is ok: `com.paramlist` has right values of `param1`, `param2`, `param3` addresses. So, what is the right initialization of `pramlist` array?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/b9zuq_

Comment: The members of `com.paramlist` are not all zero: [I get different values](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77f4902da3d36294).

Comment: Possibly a bug in the `STM32F303VC` compiler?

Comment: Please add the missing code ([mcve]), how do you create the object and how do you know that the pointers are all zero?

Comment: Also, be sure you don't want [member pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/pointer-to-class-data-member) into Tltecom instances rather than plain pointers.

Comment: Also , if i use 'constexpr static char param1[20], param2[20] ,param3[8]' and 'constexpr static char * paramlist[]={(char*) param1,(char*) param2,(char*) param3}' everything is ok!

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I tried to use them (backticks). Explain, please, why the code sentence is not grey.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Thank u. I understood. `code`

Comment: Thanks! The problem was solved! I forgot to call constructors from startup code. The following may be usefull for someone:

`extern void(*__init_array_start)();
extern void(*__init_array_end)();
 
for (void(**p)() = &__init_array_start; p < &__init_array_end; p++)
(*p)();`