# (Why) can we assign non-static class members to static variables in initialization?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, static

In a larger code base I have encountered code like this ([see on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/XhYBr_)):

```
struct Foo {};

struct Base {
    Foo* a;
};

struct Bar : public Base {
    static Foo* Bar::*mybar[];
};

Foo* Bar::Bar::*mybar[] = {
    &Base::a
};
```

To be honest, I'm baffled. This looks like it's initializing a static array of `Foo` pointers in `Bar` with a non-static member variable of `Base`. How is that even possible without an object?

*(Disclaimer: This is found in production code that actually works - hopefully not relying on UB?)*

Also, is there any problem if I remove the qualified name lookup like [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MxVrn3)? I'd like to refactor the code and make it more readable. All these `Bar::`s seem quite superfluous, but since I'm not feeling so comfortable with the code I'd rather understand the implications first.

Comment: Are you confusing `&Base::a` the member pointer with `Base b; &b.a;` the object pointer?

Comment: Is the production code really `Foo *Bar::Bar::*mybar`, or is it `Foo *Bar::* Bar::mybar`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thanks for your note: Indeed this was a typo - I have updated my question including the godbolt links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, `Bar::mybar` is an array of [pointers to members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/pointer-to-class-data-member). Those aren't actual pointers. They are more like an abstraction over an offset into the object. They allow accessing members indirectly. Given a `Base` object (or one derived from it), we can invoke them, as follows

```
aBar.*mybar[0] // This resolve to a Foo* inside aBar
```

The other thing of note, is that in your example the object in namespace scope is not the definition of `Bar::mybar`. It's an unrelated array. The correct definition would be

```
Foo* Bar::* Bar::mybar[] = {
    &Base::a
};
```

It is because your definition was wrong that removing some of the qualified name had no effect. When you removed it, you were left with

```
static Foo *mybar[];

Foo Bar::*mybar[] = {
    &Base::a
};
```

The types of the declaration and "definition" mismatch. But you got no error because those are in fact different objects.

In the correct definition, every `Bar::` qualifier is required and serves a different purpose. One serves to create the correct type (pointer to member of `Bar`), the other designates the static member of `Bar` that is being defined, and is required in every static class member definition.

Comment: Thanks for your note: Indeed this was a typo - I have updated my question including the godbolt links. But [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MxVrn3), if the lines 8 and 11 don't coincide, why does line 11 even compile if there is no corresponding declaration in `Bar`?

Comment: I already addressed that in my answer. Your definition does not correspond to any declaration in `Bar`. It's a namespace scoped delcaration of the form `TYPE mybar[]  = { ... };`. That does not define a member of `Bar`. To do that you need `TYPE Bar::mybar ...`

Comment: Wow, that was a quick reply :-) I think that I understood what you mean, but need to dig a little bit deeper. But you definitely addressed the point where the shoe pinches! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Unlike normal pointers, class member pointers can be though of as an offset into the class, where they are telling you which member of an object they point to.  So in your code, `mybar` is an array of class member pointers.  When you do

```
Foo *Bar::Bar::*mybar[] = {
    &Base::a
};
```

you initialize the array with a pointer to the `a` member of `Base`.  This isn't actually pointing to an `a`, it just tells the compiler which member of the object to return if you access it with an object.  That would look like

```
Base foo; // now we have an actual object
foo.*mybar[0]; // access the `a` member of `foo` by using the "offset"
```

Answer (score 3):

> How is that even possible without an object?

It is possible to create pointer to member variables without an object. The pointers can be used to dereference an actual member only in the presence of an object.

Simpler example:

```
struct Foo { int m; int n};

using MemberPtr = int Foo::*;

MemberPtr p1 = &Foo::m;  // Instance of Foo is not needed.
MemberPtr p2 = &Foo::n;  // Instance of Foo is not needed.

*p1 = 10; //  Not allowed.
*p2 = 20; //  Not allowed.

Foo a;
a.*p1 = 10;  // Changes a.m
a.*p2 = 20;  // Changes a.n

Foo b;
b.*p1 = 30;  // Changes b.m
b.*p2 = 40;  // Changes b.n
```

Please note that you are able to change values of members of two instances of the class using the same pointer to member variables.