# What does taking an address of a non-static struct field without a struct instance yield?

Tags: c++

Minimal code reproducible code:

```
struct Struct
{
    int value;
    int* a;
};

template <typename T>
void Print(T value)
{
    int size = sizeof(value);
    printf("%d %d\n", value, size);
}

int main()
{
    auto aAddress = &Struct::a;
    Print(aAddress);
    return 0;
}
```

In function `main()`, I take the address of a non-static field `a` through `Struct` type name without instantiating it. A few questions:

1. What is the resulting type of `aAddress`? Clang and GCC both reports its size to be `sizeof(void*)` (4 bytes when compiled to 32-bit code, and 8 bytes when compiled to 64-bit code), whereas MSVC reports its size to be 4 bytes no matter whether you compile code as 32-bit or 64-bit.
2. What is the value of `aAddress` supposed to be? On all three compilers (Clang, GCC, MSVC) it seems to be equal to `offsetof(Struct, a)`. Is this a mere coincidence (and the actual result is undefined) or is it indeed equal to offset of that field from the beginning of the struct?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger? Debuggers should be able to show you the type of a particular object.

Comment: I did... Visual Studio debugger seems to think that the type is `int**` which makes no sense on 64-bit since its size is not 8.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer - see pointer to data member

Comment: `&Struct::a` is of type `int Struct::*`   (a pointer to an `int` member of `Struct`).   It is implementation-defined what `sizeof` yields for that type - nothing preventsit from being equal to `sizeof(void *)` and no rule prevents it being non-equal.   If `o` is an instance of `Struct`, then `o.*aAddress` in your code accesses `o.a`.

Comment: please one question per question.

Comment: `printf("%d %d\n", value, size);` This is wrong in general, and will actually fail if either or both arguments are wider than an `int`.

Comment: pointers to members is an abstraction. The standard specifies what you can do with such pointer, how it is implemented is implementation details. You can think of it as an offset with respect to the adress of an object yes

Comment: there is a simple trick to make the compiler tell you the type https://godbolt.org/z/4G1d51

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but a question that starts by knowing what the type of `aAddress` is: [Pointer to class data member “::*”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/pointer-to-class-data-member).