# Point to a struct member?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, typedef

I have the following `typedef`ined `struct`:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t u8Byte1;             // This byte takes the needed values sometimes
    uint8_t u8Byte2;             // Not used
    uint8_t u8Byte3;             // This byte takes the needed values the other times
    uint8_t u8Byte4;             // Not used
} tstrMapMetadata;
```

And I have a thread that fills (with data from a sensor) this struct and uses one of its values:

```
while(true)
{
  tstrMapMetadata * pstrMapMetadata = something();
  
  if(pstrMapMetadata->u8Byte1 == SOMETHING) //<---- this line
  {
    //Do something special 
  }
}
```

But now I have a `condition` (constant during the thread) in which I want the comparison of the marked line done with `u8Byte3` instead of `u8Byte1`.

Of course I could

```
if(((condition) ? pstrMapMetadata->u8Byte1 : pstrMapMetadata->u8Byte3) == SOMETHING) //<---- this line
```

But the I would be doing **the same** comparison all the time.

Is there a way to point to one of the members (are they called like this?) of the struct before its declaration?

Something like (this code of course doesn't work but gives an idea of what I'm looking for):

```
uint8_t * coolPointer;
if(condition) 
{
  coolPointer = (someOperation)tstrMapMetadata(u8Byte1);
}
else
{
  coolPointer = (someOperation)tstrMapMetadata(u8Byte3);
}

while(true)
{
  tstrMapMetadata * pstrMapMetadata = something();
  
  if(coolPointer == SOMETHING) //<---- this line
  {
    //Do something special 
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the first approach?

Comment: @WaisKamal it makes a comparison that will have the **same** result all the time, I would like this comparison to be done only once before the `while` loop starts

Comment: Do you mean that `u8Byte1` and `u8Byte3` always have the same value?

Comment: @WaisKamal no, I meant that inside the loop `case` doesn't change

Comment: @Jarod42 of course! sorry, I'm editing that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [pointer to member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members):

```
uint8_t tstrMapMetadata::*member = condition ?
     &tstrMapMetadata::u8Byte1 :
     &tstrMapMetadata::u8Byte3;

while (true)
{
  tstrMapMetadata* pstrMapMetadata = something();
  
  if (pstrMapMetadata->*member == SOMETHING) // usage with ->*  ( .* for objet )
  {
    //Do something special 
  }
}
```

Comment: Side note (@Ivan): Using `auto member = ...` works fine here, too...

Comment: Congratulations, you've found a use for one of the most obscure and least-used features in the language. In fact, I'm here because I was wondering what a proper use case would look like.

Comment: In the end you could do the same with a normal pointer to int, couldn't you

Comment: @AndrewBloom: we have 2 variables here: the class object, and the member accessor. That cannot be replaced by a simple pointer on `int` without some rewrite.

Comment: I see, object changes inside the while. Thanks for clarifying. So an alternative would be having u8Byte as array and condition to determine the index. But that requires to change the original class.