# how to pass class member address to a function so that assign it to a class member pointer inside the function?

Tags: c++

given a class like

```
class Person{
public:
    int age;
    string name;
    Person( int i, string n ):age(i), name(n){}

};
```

If we have a global class member pointer, we can do something like this:

```
int Person::*class_member_ptr;
class_member_ptr = &Person::age;
```

But what if we wanna do the same thing in a function, what is the function signature, and how do we pass Person::age into this function such that:

```
void func( Person::age ){

   class_member_ptr = &Person::age;
}
```

the data type of the argument in the func() is wrong. it can't be compiled. How do we make the data type of the argument right?

Comment: `void func (int Person::*member_ptr) {...`

Comment: @PaulSanders, your syntax works out!!!  Appreciate it!

Comment: Kind of question that can be answered with a search on the web in far less time it took you to write the question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer to class data member "::\*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/pointer-to-class-data-member)