# Why does printing address of data member of a struct enabled, although there is no object?

Tags: c++, pointers, member-pointers

Suppose I have the following code. I have expected that this has to at least give me a warning.

```
#include <iostream>

struct test
{
    int whatever;
};

int main()
{
    int test::* p = &test::whatever;    
    std::cout << p;
}
```

However, I was surprised to find out that this code compiles without complaints. So I would like to know, what is actually printed in this case, how is the `test::whatever` stored, so we can access its address?

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer to class data member "::\*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/pointer-to-class-data-member)

Comment: OP asks why it is possible to make a pointer of something that does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how is the test::whatever stored

This is not specified in the language. But we can make a reasonable guess that it stores an offset from the beginning of the object to the pointed member.

> so we can access its address?

No.

> what is actually printed in this case

1 is printed.

There is no operator overload for member pointers. But there is an overload for bool and member pointers are convertible to bool. They convert to true when they aren't null. `p` isn't null, so it converts to true which prints as 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here *p* is pointer to member. It is like an offset of the class member relative to the object base address. It doesn't point to anywhere in memory by itself. It needs a base object pointer to point somewhere. Therefore it is not illegal to have a pointer to member without an object, just the opposite: it is the use case of this type.

You can use it like:

```
#include <iostream>

struct test
{
    int whatever;
};

int main()
{
    int test::* p = &test::whatever;

    test t = {5};
    std::cout << t.*p << std::endl; // prints 5
}
```

However, I don't know what is printed out in the example you gave.

See Pointer-to-Member ->* and .* Operators in C++.

Comment: I know what it does. I wanted to know why the code above compiles.

Comment: Because it is the use case of this type of pointer. You store and pass the relative address of a member to base address of an object of the class/struct. And it is only meaningful when you have a real object. @KarenBaghdasaryan

Answer (score 0):

It is member pointer, as already pointed in first answer. You can use it to point to different members of different objects:

```cpp
struct test
{
    int whatever;
};

int main()
{
    int test::* p = &test::whatever;
    test w1{ 123 }, w2{ 234 };
    std::cout << p<< endl; //point to member
    std::cout << w1.*p << endl; //value of first whatever
    std::cout << w2.*p << endl; //value of second whatever

    //real address of whatever of w1 and w2, compare
    std::cout << &(w1.*p) << "=="<< &w1.whatever<< endl;
    std::cout << &(w2.*p) << "=="<< &w2.whatever<< endl;

    std::cout << p << endl; //yet pointer did not change
    return 0;
}
```