# Understanding libunifex's member_t template metaprogramming facility

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming

I'm currently trying to understand the [`std::execution` proposal](https://wg21.link/p2300) by studying [libunifex](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/libunifex)'s implementation. The library makes heavy use of template metaprogramming.

There's one piece of code I really have trouble understanding:

```cpp
template <class Member, class Self>
Member Self::* _memptr(const Self&);

template <typename Self, typename Member>
using member_t = decltype(
    (std::declval<Self&&>() .*
     _memptr<Member>(std::declval<Self&&>())));
```

What exactly is `member_t` used for? It's used in the implementation of `then`:

```cpp
template <typename Sender, typename Receiver>
    requires std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<Sender>, type> &&
        receiver<Receiver> &&
        sender_to<member_t<Sender, Predecessor>, receiver_t<std::remove_cvref_t<Receiver>>>
friend auto tag_invoke(tag_t<connect>, Sender&& s, Receiver&& r)
noexcept(
    std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<std::remove_cvref_t<Receiver>, Receiver> &&
    std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<Function, member_t<Sender, Function>> &&
    is_nothrow_connectable_v<member_t<Sender, Predecessor>, receiver_t<std::remove_cvref_t<Receiver>>>
    // ----------------------^ here
)
-> connect_result_t<member_t<Sender, Predecessor>, receiver_t<std::remove_cvref_t<Receiver>>> { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Looks like some kind of templated [pointer to class member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/670740/4074081) access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_memptr` is a function declared in such a way that

```
_memptr<Member>(self)
```

will give you a *pointer to member of <class type of `self`> of type `Member`* regardless of `self`'s `const`ness or value category. So if `Self` is possibly a reference type,

```
Member Self::*
```

would be ill-formed, but `decltype(_memptr<Member>(std::declval<Self&&>()))` will still give you the type you want.

---

The result of applying `std::declval<Self&&>() .*` to the member pointer is that it will produce the referenced member with the value category one would expect from a member access expression via `.` when the left-hand side has the value category indicated by `Self`'s reference-qualification. That means if `Self` is a lvalue reference the expression will also be a lvalue and if `Self` is a rvalue reference or a non-reference the result will be a xvalue (rvalue).

Applying `decltype` to the expression gives you correspondingly a lvalue or rvalue reference to the member's type. It tells you whether, given the value category of `self` as a forwarding reference with template parameter `Self` its member of type `Member` should be moved from or instead copied where necessary.

Now if you have e.g.

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& t) {
    auto s = (member_t<T, decltype(t.s)>)(t.s);
}
```

where `s` is a non-reference non-static data member of `T`, then `s` will be copy-constructed from `t.s` if `f` is passed a lvalue and move-constructed from it if passed a rvalue. Essentially it is `std::forward` for the member.

In your shown code it is not directly used this way, but instead the member's type with correct reference-qualification is passed to some type trait e.g. in `std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<Function, member_t<Sender, Function>>` to to check whether `Function` can be (nothrow) constructed from a `Function` lvalue or rvalue depending on whether or not `s` was passed a lvalue or rvalue.

---

It think this performs an equivalent action to what `std::forward_like` in C++23 will do when used as

```
template <typename Self, typename Member>
using member_t = decltype(std::forward_like<Self>(std::declval<Member>()));
```

---

(I would not call that template metaprogramming by the way. Nothing here is using template instantiations to implement some algorithm at compile-time.)